# CodeIgniter URL param is not detected by inherited controller

Tags: codeigniter, url

app/core/BaseController.php

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }
}
```

app/controllers/abc.php

```
class Abc extends BaseController {
  public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }
  public function test($id) {
    echo $id;
  }
}
```

Opening URL `abc/test/10` returns error that the function `test` misses argument ($id). But if `Abc` controller inherits directly to `CI_Controller`, runs well.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that you put in application/core/ will either replace or extend a class of the same name in system/core - though for this to work you must prefix the classname with MY_ (extend) or CI_ (replace). See [the manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html).

Since there is no class called BaseController in system/core, I'm guessing what you want is something like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() { 
      parent::__construct(); 
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Abc extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }
    public function test($id) {
      echo $id;
    }
}
```

If the above is not what you need, you'll have to explain what you want to achieve with BaseController.

Comment: I need some custom common functions in all controllers, eg. to return JSON output (`$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($output))`), a function to shorten this can be declared in a "master controller", and controllers will extend it.
After I rename `BaseController.php` to `MY_Controller.php` in app/core folder, the class name to MY_Controller as well, and controllers extend MY_Controller. But URL `abc/test/0` still doesn't work.